# Qt QXmlStreamReader Access Violation

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

I am using Qt 5.11.1(MSVSC2015 32bit) and QtCreator 4.6.2.
I am having trouble parsing XML with QXmlStreamReader. Code is written based on [Qt's example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-streambookmarks-example.html).
When my code is executed it produces access violation in QIODevice.cpp in checkWarnMessage function.
This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG1kP.png) shows call stack and exact line where access violation occurred.

The actual XML i more complex and has nested elements. Functions that parse XML are implemented same way as void XbelReader::readXBEL() function from Qt's example (based on element name appropriate function is called to parse that element). But with this simple example I have managed to reproduce problem I have in actual solution.

XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element1>1</element1>
    <element2>2</element2>
    <element3>3</element3>
    <element4>4</element4>
    <element5>5</element5>
    <element6>6</element6>
</root>
```

Code that parses this XML is:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>

#define ASSERT_ELEMENT_NAME(NAME) Q_ASSERT(xmlReader.isStartElement() && xmlReader.name() == NAME);

using namespace std;

void OpenFile(const QString& fileName, QXmlStreamReader& xmlReader)
{
    QFile configFile(fileName);
    if (configFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text) == false)
        throw runtime_error(string("Failed to open file: ") + configFile.errorString().toStdString());

    xmlReader.setDevice(&configFile);
    if (xmlReader.readNextStartElement() == false)
        throw runtime_error("File does not have root element");

    if (xmlReader.name() != "root")
        throw runtime_error("File has invalid root element");
}

void ParseElement1(QXmlStreamReader& xmlReader)
{
    ASSERT_ELEMENT_NAME("element1");

    auto text = xmlReader.readElementText().trimmed();
    auto isOk = false;
    auto value = text.toInt(&isOk);

    if (isOk == false)
        throw runtime_error(string("invalid value: ") + text.toStdString());
    else
        cout << "element1: " << value << endl;
}

void ParseElement2(QXmlStreamReader& xmlReader)
{
    ASSERT_ELEMENT_NAME("element2");

    auto text = xmlReader.readElementText().trimmed();
    auto isOk = false;
    auto value = text.toInt(&isOk);

    if (isOk == false)
        throw runtime_error(string("invalid value: ") + text.toStdString());
    else
        cout << "element2: " << value << endl;
}

int main()
{
    QXmlStreamReader xmlReader;

    OpenFile("config.xml", xmlReader);

    while(xmlReader.readNextStartElement())
    {
        if(xmlReader.name() == "element1")
            ParseElement1(xmlReader);
        if(xmlReader.name() == "element2")
            ParseElement2(xmlReader);
        else
            xmlReader.skipCurrentElement();
    }
}
```

If I comment two lines in main function:

```
        if(xmlReader.name() == "element2")
            ParseElement2(xmlReader);
```

access violation does not happen.

I really can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Or is there a bug in QXmlStreamReader? I think that even in case I did something wrong, access violation should not happen in Qt's library.

Entire project (XmlParser.pro, main.cpp and config.xml) can be downloaded from this [link](https://uploadfiles.io/a7c52)

**EDIT**

I have fixed my example as Manthan suggested and it worked as expected. I have added one more thing to the XML. I have added large multiline comment before element1. Comment itself has 8019 characters, including whitespace characters, whereas entire XML file has 8266 characters.

XML now looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <!--
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, 
    comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment,
    comment, comment, co
    -->
    <element1>1</element1>
    <element2>2</element2>
    <element3>3</element3>
    <element4>4</element4>
    <element5>5</element5>
    <element6>6</element6>
</root>
```

I have checked that XML is valid in Notepad++ with XML Tools plugin and also on xmlvalidation.xml. When I execute fixed example with new XML, again I have access violation on exact same place depicted on previously linked image.

Now, if I remove last "o" character from comment in XML(or any other character from comment, or e.g. "6" from text of element6, or as a matter of fact any character from XML while keeping XML valid), example is executed successfully. And this is my original problem. I have a lot of comments in my original XML file, resulting file to be larger that 8KB. For now, as a workaround, I remove comments to avoid access violation.

It is not clear to me how does comment (or file) length causes access violation.

Entire project can be downloaded from this [link](https://ufile.io/fb93u)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is within while loop. Update it as below.

```
while(xmlReader.readNextStartElement())
{
    if(xmlReader.name() == "element1")
        ParseElement1(xmlReader);
    else if(xmlReader.name() == "element2")
        ParseElement2(xmlReader);
    else
        xmlReader.skipCurrentElement();
}
```

In your code, first element is of type 'element1' then first it process (with first `if`) and they again it come to `else` where it try to skip it, which cause problem.

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you very much!
But regardless of my dumb mistake, shouldn't QXmlStreamReader have some checking of precondition?

Comment: @ scopchanov, Sorry. This was my first post. After you comment, I have tried to upvote answer, but I got message that "votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed score.

Comment: @Aleksandar, I understand! Try now ;)